# raise_application_error reuse of the error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I was wondering if theres a way in which I can decide that from "this day on" a user-defined error can act as a resource I can use over and over.

For example->
Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'The balance is too low.');

So basically if I can use -20343 as key word(error code) and use again in a different procedure instead of raising it again and again..,
Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, you can reuse code -20343, but - what do you mean by "**instead of** raising it again and again"? When you find out that balance is too low, you'll have to *raise* the exception.

Comment: I mean for example, I have a new procedure now, lets make it simple and say the procedure is that exact same ( checking for balance ), now, when declaring that 2nd procedure, do I have to explicitly write  Raise_Application_Error (-20343, 'The balance is too low.') ? OR can I store it as an error and then in procedure call it like "IF Balance<X -> -20343 or raise_application_error(-20343). I hope I was clear @Littlefoot .edit* that example might be wrong but lets assume I have 1000chars error, how can I reuse it in a new procedure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you'll have to raise it, somehow, Oracle can't know what you want to do if *balance is too low*.

Maybe you could create your own table of exceptions, e.g.

```
SQL> select * from my_exception;

  ERR_CODE ERR_NAM ERR_MESSAGE
---------- ------- ------------------------------
    -20343 bal_low Balance is too low
    -20344 name_s  Name can not begin with an "S"
```

Function accepts error code and returns message:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_myerr (par_err_code in my_exception.err_code%type)
  2    return my_exception.err_message%type
  3  is
  4    retval my_exception.err_message%type;
  5  begin
  6    select err_message
  7      into retval
  8      from my_exception
  9      where err_code = par_err_code;
 10    return retval;
 11  exception
 12    when no_data_found then
 13      return 'Exception does not exist';
 14  end;
 15  /

Function created.
```

This piece of code *simulates* "balance too low" error:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_balance number;
  3    bal_low   exception;
  4  begin
  5    select sal into l_balance
  6      from emp
  7      where ename = 'JONES';
  8
  9    if l_balance < 5000 then
 10       raise bal_low;
 11    end if;
 12
 13  exception
 14    when bal_low then
 15      raise_application_error(-20343, f_myerr(-20343));
 16  end;
 17  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20343: Balance is too low
ORA-06512: at line 15


SQL>
```

Another PL/SQL procedure might also find out that balance is too low, but you'd have to repeat such a code again, I'm afraid.

---

You can modify that code (i.e. table, function) to better suit your needs, but - that's what I understood for what you said so far.